# Is it possible to define multiple model objects that with same class name in different folders?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

folder_a/models.py

```
class Category(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "category_a"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('category_a.id'))
    parent = db.relationship('Category',
                         primaryjoin='Category.parent_id == Category.id',
                         remote_side=id, backref=db.backref('children'))
```

folder_b/models.py

```
class Category(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "category_b"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('category_b.id'))
    parent = db.relationship('Category',
                         primaryjoin='Category.parent_id == Category.id',
                         remote_side=id, backref=db.backref('children'))
```

But I can't use SQLAlchemy create_all() to init database.
How can I do in this situation if I don't wang to change the class name?
Thanks!

Comment: And what error and traceback you get on MetaData.create_all?

Comment: It looks like an occasion to use inheritance.

Comment: @VictorGavro `sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Multiple classes found for path "Category" in the registry of this declarative base. Please use a fully module-qualified path.`

Comment: So, do what it says: `db.relationship("folder_a.models.Category", ...)`; or, just use a direct reference: `db.relationship(lambda: Category, ...)`.